# CDI sessionscoped event being fired by web service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am confused with my current situation: I created a REST service which takes requests from the user client browser. Then the service fires an event to invoke a method of the session bean. However, I am not sure if multiple users are using my web app, what will happen when the event is fired? Will all of their sessionscoped beans get the event, or only the one of the user who requested the service?

Comment: could you elaborate? post some code?

Comment: Hi, for example, I have one web service which has a method {at}Post public void doSomething(SomeEvent event){ eventService.fire(event)}, the other bean looks like {at}SessionScoped public void doSomething(@Observes SomeEvent event) {}.